# How to change iPhone UITableView delete button title while editing it

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I need to change the title of the default delete button that appears when I attempt to delete a row from a `UITableView` after setting editing to `YES`.

Comment: Are you aware we have no idea of what language/system/framework/platform you are talking about?

Comment: Hello guy! If you can just add ANYTHING about what are you even doing, it would quite nice...

Comment: ok, i've updated the question, sorry!

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can change it in UITableView delegate method

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Thank you,
but i did add that method and returned NSString like that

return @"Remove";

and nothing happened, it displays the default title "Delete"

Comment: @Vladimir, is it possible to change background for Delete button? Defaults its showing Delete button with white background.

Comment: @Hemang, don't remember seeing white "delete" button in standard UI - I think there's no open API for that

Comment: @Vladimir, Sorry! Its misunderstanding there! The Delete button with red color only, but it views background is of white color. Button is at center of that view. Its not my custom view or anything, I just override this method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and it will showing me Delete button when I swipe on any cell in my `UITableView`.

Comment: @Vladimir, What I want to do is to clear the background of that view! So that only Delete button will be show on any cell.

Comment: @Hemang, not sure, may be setting cell's background color to clearColor may help? delete button just comes over cell's contentView or the cell itself and does not add any extra background, need to experiment with that to be sure

Comment: what about if I want to change the background color of the delete button @Vladimir

Comment: @007, afaik there's no public api for that. You can try to check views hierarchy and change background directly. But keep in mind that as it is implementation details this structure may change (and has already changed) between ios versions.

Answer (score 7):

### Swift

Add this method to your `UITableView` delegate (probably your view controller).

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> String? {
    return "Erase"
}
```

This makes the button say "Erase" but you can use any string you want.

[image]

My fuller answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37719543/3681880).

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3**

With a small difference _

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> String? {
    return "Erase"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For those who** already have implemented method 'titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath' and **still see same 'Delete' text.**

Try to **type in** method **from scratch** with autocompletion, because I copied someone's and it has a little bit different older notation and didn't get called!