# How to change uitableview delete button text

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, delegates

Hi there I am trying to change the text that is showing in the delete button when a user swipes a uitableviewcell inside my tableview.

I have seen an example in another question thread that says to use this tableview delegate

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

My question is, how do I use this method.. I am not sure how to use this.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

In your controller managing the `UITableView` you should implement the `UITableviewDelegate` and return the title you want for your method inside the `titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Example:

```
@interface CategoryAddViewController : UITableViewController
@end

@implementation CategoryAddViewController
// ...
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return @"Please don't delete me!";
}

@end
```

Leaving you off with something like that:

[image]

Comment: Great, but why doesn't the appearance of the button animate any more? After adding this, the delete button pops up instead of being animated! Edit: My bad, must have been a sim glitch. After restarting the app its ok again.

Comment: @FaizanS. I am looking into this as well. Is there no way to just change the property? Something like ... ``self.tableView.deleteButton.name = @"Remove";`` instead of overriding the method?

Comment: Not as of the time of writing. In the iOS SDK many things are achiev ed by overriding existing methods of base UI classes.

Comment: the swift way: `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> String{
        return "Remove Me";
    }`

Comment: In this answer there is no reason to add `<UITableViewDelegate>`.

Answer (score 31):

In Swift it is equal, just method signature is diferent!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> String? {
  return "Erase"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just return the string that you want to display instead of delete. Say you wish to show "Erase" for all rows, the above function should contain:

```
return @"Erase";
```

Read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607155/how-to-change-iphone-uitableview-delete-button-title-while-editing-it)

Also in your .h file, add the UITableViewDelegate in case your view controller is not a UITableViewController already. That is it can be either:

```
@interface SomeView : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>
```

OR

```
@interface SomeView : UITableViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> String? {
        return "Erase"
    }
```